# Triple boot Ubuntu 13.10 with Windows 7 and Kali Linux

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have Windows 7 installed initially and then I installed Kali Linux using the GRUB bootloader on my system. I want to triple boot these with Ubuntu 13.10. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Boot Ubuntu live-disk and select **Try Ubuntu** option on startup.
- Now open Gparted Partition Editor from Dash and create a separate ext4 partition (primary or logical) for Ubuntu.
- Now run the Ubuntu installer and choose something else option to install Ubuntu on a newly created ext4 partition.
- After Ubuntu installation has completed, run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) if necessary.

Comment: Thank you. What if i burn the .iso file in usb and click on the install ubuntu file. Will this not help. Or is this option going to create some kind of disturbance in my system ?

Comment: did you already created a seperate partition for ubuntu?

Comment: yeah that i can do from windows disk management as I did to install kali linux

Comment: which type of partition you created for ubuntu?I think you can't able to create ext4 partition from disk management.

Comment: well that would be an unallocated sapce where i wud be installing ubuntu.

Comment: If you doesn't had any os's installed on your hard-disk and left only unallocated space means Ubuntu installer automatically convert the unallocated space into ext4 partition and install ubuntu on it.But you had already windows and kali linux so you must follow my answer,otherwise there may be some chance of os loss.

Comment: Yeah got it. Thanks for ur help. Just one more thing. What if i create install ubuntu- is that going to create any problem or that option is equally safe?

Comment: create,choose something else,install it doesn't create any problem.If you face any problem post that as a question in this site.

Comment: Ya sure. Let me try it once then I would definitely do that and also since I am a new user to dis forum i wud take time to figure things out.

Comment: Ofcourse I would.

Answer (score 0):

Triple Booting works much the same as dual booting. Install the first OS and then install the second and so on. The only things that I have found that you have to watch out for is to have a separate partition for each OS that you want on the system and if you are installing MS Windows, Windows *must* be installed first as the windows installer has a tendency to delete the grub bootloader and install its own.

for futher reading check out these links:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=857214

[How do I triple-boot Ubuntu, Fedora and Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156045/how-do-i-triple-boot-ubuntu-fedora-and-windows-7)

[Can you triple-boot safely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262503/can-you-triple-boot-safely)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Just wanted to clarify - the grub wont create a problem right, while I install ubuntu?

Comment: To @user237156 answer I'll add one more thing - make sure you do NOT mount /home of one of the Linux distros as /home of the other. There is a high chance that configuration files will be overwritten and and it might screw up something. As for your question "The GRUB won't create a problem righ?" - it shouldn't but who knows. :) That's why smart people do a backup before they start installing such a huge thing as an OS. ;)

Comment: ohkay.. and as for backup..i already had done it :)