# Installing third OS on a dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

Presently, I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10. I am planning to install one more linux distro alongside both. My question is, will my present GRUB be deleted and a new GRUB installed, or will both be present as separate boot entries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you triple-boot safely?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/262503/can-you-triple-boot-safely)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will only have 1 main bootloader.

It depends on what that 3rd OS is and if that OS lets you skip installing the bootloader from that installation on what happens to your system.

When you are done you can use an Ubuntu live session to install [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and use it to re-install (for instance) Grub if you run into trouble.

Comment: If my 3rd OS is linux mint, will my GRUB of Ubuntu 16.04 vanish from the boot menu? and GRUB from mint install overtake that?

Comment: What if i prefer to install 3rd OS on an external device? Will it be safe?

Comment: 1st one: yes, yes. 2nd: yes. And you can always reinstall a bootloader after installing them all.