# Dual boot with Virtual Machine

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, kubuntu, mint

I already have a dual boot system with Kubuntu + Windows 10

Now, I have to install linux mint for a project which Needs to be done using Virtual machine.

When assignment of location and space..

1. Erase disk and install linux mint
2. Something else

I read several websites that choosing 1st option wouldn’t affect windows OS and data but **I want to ask whether it is safe for my dual booted Kubuntu?**

Would it clear Kubuntu on the partition then.?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you triple-boot safely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262503/can-you-triple-boot-safely)

Comment: It doesn’t triple boot. The system configuration now looks like: DUAL BOOT (windows + Kubuntu ). Inside windows it has VM machine which has Linux Mint OS.

Comment: I know you currently have a dual boot on your computer. I interpreted your question as asking if it's safe to convert your current dual boot of Kubuntu and Windows 10 into a triple boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safe in a virtual machine. You can Select the option of Erase disk. Virtual Machine makes an environment to make an os feel like it is in a real machine. I myself have tried this with Ubuntu and no it will not use or harm the Linux Mint as it has its own partition